# C# dictionary size is a prime number

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary

I was reading the source code of the dictionary and came across the resize method. I saw the formula `temp = (currentSize * 2), currentSize = GetNextPrimalNumber(temp)`. Why we must to set primal number as a dictionary size? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,440

Can somebody explain why we should use primal numbers as a size of dictionary? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Look at line 356.  A dictionary key must be unique. If you have 8 bits for the key you only have 256 unique values.  When you add the 257 value you must increase the size of the key to 9 bits.